# Sub-site group not displayed in site permissions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, groups

SharePoint 2010.  I have a parent site and a sub-site.  The sub-site was not inherited and had its own groups.  Somehow inheritance got turned on, and now only the inherited parent groups are showing in the sub-site Site Permissions page.  When i broke inheritance to the sub-site, i still only see the parent site groups.  The original sub-site groups still exist as i can grant access to them (although they say `"no access"`).  How do i get these original groups to show back up in the Site Permissions page so i can change the permission level on them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Site Actions, Site Permissions and add the groups back in from the Grant Permission button. Click it, add the group(s) and assign the permission level and click Ok.